# Best way to save Excel row reference

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a C# application with a SQL Server database.

One functionality of the application is to read a big Excel file and go row by row trying to match an `ID` column with an `ID` in the database. Once a row matches, then some of the values are stored in a table.

Later the user is able to change the value on that table but I would like have a way to audit the original values. So I was thinking on creating an XML column in that table that will store the original values of the whole Excel row.

I don't need to implement audit trail to the table, just want to keep the Excel reference row in my SQL Server table for future audit.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you only ever need a single previous version? If users can make multiple edits then maybe it would be easier to add a "version" column to the table itself, and on every edit you insert a new row with an incremented version number. Or build a separate audit table that tracks field by field which values changed. The XML solution you're proposing isn't ideal IMO.

Comment: No, there is no need because it can only have one edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External storage of the old value is too hard to maintain, in the long run.

All you need to do is add an "OriginalValue_[fieldname]" column in the SQL table for each value that the user can change.  When you populate the table, put the same value in [fieldname] and [OriginalValue_fieldname].  When the user makes changes, you only change [fieldname] but the old value is right in the table.

If this won't work (i.e. you're not allowed to make schema changes), make another table with the ID fields and the original values.  Same approach -- no external data.

Comment: This is a good answer if you have a manageable number of changeable fields.  If there are too many changeable fields for that to be practical, an alternative would be to serialize your Excel data.  XML is one way to do that, but I'd recommend JSON.NET as a more lightweight solution.